# Importing existing class and use it's form visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010 express for this C# project. My partner and I divided the work, each of us worked on a different machine. How do we merge the projects in to one? when I run the imported clases I get a lot of errors, most of them seem to be because I cant use the form she created on her machine. How do I import these windows form as well??

Thanks

Comment: Is her code going to be used as a dll or are you merging the source in to one project?

Comment: This is why you use some sort of source control.

Comment: Revision Control http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm not sure what you mean. I tried adding exitsting item command and selected *.NET files. I want to be able to use forms she created

Comment: The basic problem would be that when you add a new Thing into a Visual Studio project, this thing can consist of more than one file, and they all have to be registered in the `.csproj` file for that project. This is why it's not recommended to transfer files back and forth but to share the whole project, since you then have to manually replicate what VS does, and it's not obvious what that is. Your partner probably didn't send you all the required files or you didn't add them all to your project or something.

Comment: The problem in Windows-Forms can be also that some pre-compiler or compiler configs for some files are wrong. I guess it won't be very easy for you to fix those things, maybe it would help to post the exact error messages you are getting.

Comment: if revision-/source-control is too complicated, I also know some people working over a shared dropbox-folder together, and it seems to work for small projects

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using some sort of Revision Control system.  There's online services like github that can help with that.

In the meantime, you'll have to manually merge the changes.

Alternatively, you *could* create a new project, check it into revision control, check it out in two places, copy the changes you each have made over-top, and try merging...  YMMV.